# Command line number adding program produces wrong results

Tags: c

My Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int n = argc;
  int i, a, b, sum;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    sscanf(argv[i], "%u", &a);
    b = a + sum;
    sum = b;
  }

  printf("%d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

This piece of code should do `./a 0 1 2 3` must write terminal `6` But writes `42423`.

The aim of the program was to issue the command-line arguments amount. But he does not make it correct angulation.

Comment: that is why you always need to check for the return value of `scanf()` family.

Comment: And `sscanf(argv[i], "%u", &a);` should be `sscanf(argv[i], "%d", &a);`

Answer (score 5):

`argv[0]` holds the name of the executable which most likely you don't want to include in the loop. so, you need to start the loop from `i=1`.

As per your input, the `argv[0]` does not contain a numeric value hence causing a failure to `sscanf()`, leaving `a` uninitialized.

So, in your code, the primary issue is with,

```
b = a + sum;
```

where, for the first iteration, `a` and `sum` are both uninitialized local variables having indeterminate value. So, for the very first loop, you're invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also, `a` being an `int`, you need to use `%d` format specifier for it.

Two things to mention:

1. Always check for the return value of `scanf()` family for success.
2. Always initialize your local variables.

Comment: `sum` is used before any value written to it, should certainly give compiler warning.

Comment: @WeatherVane sorta' missed that one, actually important. Updated now, thanks.  :)

Answer (score 0):

- You are getting garbage value because you are not initialized varuiable **sum** on declaration.
- Just initialize is as `sum = 0` and u will get expected result.
- Or u can use below code also.

  ```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int n = argc;
  int i, a, b, sum=0;

  for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
    a = atoi(argv[i]);     
    sum += a;
  }

   printf("%d\n", sum);
   return 0;
  }
  ```